# getView not rendering even though data shown in LogCat

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, logcat

I am dealing with android `ListView` and I faced with strange error when i inflating `ListItem`. I can't see my data on `getView` method even though datas are already shown in `LogCat`. Any Ideas ?

```
private ListViewAdapter m_adapter;
public ArrayList<String> cat = new ArrayList<String>();
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String title, character, thumbnail, totalPages;
int Code;
ViewHolder vh;
TextView titleView, charView, totalView;
ImageView thumbView, removeView;
Uri thumbUri;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.myputet);
    init_UI();
}

public void init_UI() {
    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.SHARED_PRED, 0);
    editor = preferences.edit();

    title = preferences.getString("TITLE", "");
    character = preferences.getString("CHAR", "");
    thumbnail = preferences.getString("THUMB", "");
    thumbUri = Uri.parse(thumbnail);
    totalPages = preferences.getString("TOTAL", "");
    Code = preferences.getInt("CODE", 0);

    System.out.println("Getting Title " + title);
    System.out.println("Getting character " + character);
    System.out.println("Getting thumbnail " + thumbnail);
    System.out.println("Getting thumbUri " + thumbUri);
    System.out.println("Getting totalPages " + totalPages);

    Log.v("ArrayList", cat.toString());
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    m_adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.myputet_item, cat);
    lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
}

private class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> items;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myputet_item, null);
        }

        Log.v("Title View", title);
        titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTxtView);
        charView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.charTxtView);
        totalView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.totalTxtView);
        thumbView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.charImageView);
        removeView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.removeListItem);
        if (titleView != null) {
            titleView.setText(title);
            Log.v("Update Title", title);
        }
        charView.setText(character);
        Log.v("Update character", character);
        totalView.setText(totalPages);
        Log.v("Update totalPages", totalPages);
        thumbView.setImageURI(thumbUri);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

`LogCat` Output

```
10-31 23:52:34.438: V/Title View(4568): မိခ်ိဳေစ်းကအျပန္
10-31 23:52:34.438: V/Update Title(4568): မိခ်ိဳေစ်းကအျပန္
10-31 23:52:34.438: V/Update character(4568): ကိုေရႊထူး(ျပည္)
10-31 23:52:34.438: V/Update totalPages(4568): 3
```

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70. This should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the View that you modified in `getView()`:

```
return v; // not convertView
```

On another note, every row in your ListView will be the same... `title`, `character`, etc. never change, so they will be displayed over and over.

Last, please watch Android's Romain Guy [discuss efficient adapters](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) to help speed up yours.

Comment: I already tried with return v; But it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try inflating your Views with `v = vi.inflate(R.layout.myputet_item, parent, false);`.

Comment: It could be your `myputet.xml` layout, is the ListView on the screen?